# Creating a 'parameter' that toggles between columns

Tags: powerbi

I'm using Power BI to build a bar chart to show sales split by a parameter which the user can select. I'm trying to find a method that lets the user toggle which parameter he wants the graph to be split by. For example, I have Column A - "Fruits" which is "Apples, Oranges, Mangoes" and Column B - "City" which is "New York, Chicago, Los Angeles". Using this, I create a bar graph which shows sales quantity, and split it by column A (Fruits), so that it shows sales of Apples, Oranges and Mangoes. 
I want to create a drop-down filter/parameter which allows me to toggle the view between "Fruits / City" so that the bar graph shows the split by either Fruits or City based on what is selected in that drop-down. I know there is a very easy way to do this in Tableau by using the "Parameter" option, but I cannot find a way to do this in Power BI. Does anyone know if there is a way to do it in Power BI?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add both Column A and Column B to the Axis of your bar-chart (or any chart). By doing so you create a heirarchy and the visual shows on the right top the following:

[image]

The dubble arrow will bring you to the next level (Cities) in your case where are the split arrow brings you a level deeper, all fruits in each city.

Now by adding a slicer you can even create a dropdown of cities for further filtering, the slider will interact with the bar.

[image]